# Choropleth map returning undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, choropleth

I'm attempting a choropleth map of US Counties, and am essentially using Mike Bostock's example from here https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606 I am using education instead of unemployment, but otherwise it's the same. I'd like to add just one more piece to it and have the county name display along with the rate. However, when I call the county name, I get "undefined" returned. To be clear 'rate' returns just fine, 'county' shows up undefined. Can anyone help?  Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.counties {
  fill: none;
  /*stroke: black;*/
}

.states {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var Bachelor = d3.map();

var path = d3.geoPath();

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 70])
    .rangeRound([600, 860]);

var color_domain = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
var ext_color_domain = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain(color_domain)
    .range([" #85c1e9", "#5dade2", "#3498db", "#2e86c1", "#2874a6", " #21618c"," #1b4f72"]);
var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "key")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,40)");

g.selectAll("rect")
  .data(color.range().map(function(d) {
      d = color.invertExtent(d);
      if (d[0] == null) d[0] = x.domain()[0];
      if (d[1] == null) d[1] = x.domain()[1];
      return d;
    }))
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("height", 8)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d[1]) - x(d[0]); })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d[0]); });

g.append("text")
    .attr("class", "caption")
    .attr("x", x.range()[0])
    .attr("y", -6)
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold")
    .text("% of Adults with Bachelor's or higher");

g.call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickSize(13)
    .tickFormat(function(x, i) { return i ? x : x; })
    .tickValues(color.domain()))
  .select(".domain")
    .remove();

d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "Bachelor2.tsv", function(d) { Bachelor.set(d.id, d.rate, d.county); })
    .await(ready);


function ready(error, us) {
  if (error) throw error;


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "counties")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.rate = Bachelor.get(d.id)); })
      .attr("d", path)
    .append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return (d.county +" " d.rate +"%"); });

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("class", "states")
      .attr("d", path);
}

</script>
```

Comment: If you have a check in your map data [us-10m.v1.json](https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json) you will find there are no country names exist. So you would better change another map data.

Comment: @1Cr18Ni9 The original code uses a map to set the `rate`. OP was trying to use the same map to set the `country`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

The first problem in your code lies here:

```
Bachelor.set(d.id, d.rate, d.county);
```

In both [javascript maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) and D3 maps (which are slightly different), you cannot set *two values* for the same key. Therefore, the syntax has to be:

> map.set(key, value)

Let's show it.

This works, setting the value "bar" to "foo":

```js
var myMap = d3.map();
myMap.set("foo", "bar");
console.log(myMap.get("foo"))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

However, this will not work:

```js
var myMap = d3.map();
myMap.set("foo", "bar", "baz");
console.log(myMap.get("foo"))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, the value "baz" was not set.

That was assuming that `country` is a property in your `Bachelor2.tsv` file. And that brings us to the second problem:

In your paths, this is the data:

```
topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features
```

If you look at your code, you set a property named `rate` (using your map) to that data...

```
.attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.rate = Bachelor.get(d.id)); })
//you set 'rate' to the datum here --------^
```

...but you never set a property named `country`. Therefore, there is no such property for you to use in the callbacks.

As explained above, you cannot set it using the same map you used to set the `rate`. A solution is using an object instead. Alternatively, you could use **two** maps, which seems to be the fastest option.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo. I was wondering if two maps might be the simplest option. I appreciate the help!