# Trouble building on Bostock d3 choropleth .tsv example

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, topojson, choropleth

I'm stumped by what I'd hoped would be a minor tweak to Mike Bostock's unemployment choropleth (  https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606 ): adding the county names and state abbreviations to the .tsv file.

I created a new unemployment2.tsv by merging Bostock's original with a list of county ID codes, names and states from the Census bureau. A sample:

```
id    rate    state    county
01001    5.1    AL    Autauga County
01003    4.9    AL    Baldwin County
...
56043    4.5    WY    Washakie County
56045    4.9    WY    Weston County
```

In the javascript, I modified the d3.queue() block as follows, in an attempt to access the state and county columns:

```
d3.queue()
.defer(d3.json, "https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json")
.defer(d3.tsv, "unemployment2.tsv", function(d) {
    unemployment.set(d.id, +d.rate, d.county, d.state);
    county = d.county;
    state = d.state;
     })
.await(ready);
```

I then modified the tooltip line of the svg.append block as follows:

```
.text(function(d) { return d.id + " - " + county + ", " + state + " - " + d.rate + "%"; });
```

The resulting map does access the new columns in the .tsv file, but the tooltip displays the county and state *only* from the last line (Weston County, WY) no matter which county you mouse over. (Oddly, the id and rate fields *do* reflect the correct county in the tooltip.)

I’m seeing the same behavior on my server as on Plunker ( https://plnkr.co/edit/vrm4FuBVEQc7lCSnbytl?p=preview ).

Appreciate any insights as to what I'm doing wrong/how to fix.

Comment: You are setting county and state as a variable, not as a property of each datum. So each time you run the row function you overwrite the variable. d3.tsv. Each row is parsed as an object, you just need to access the right properties: `d.county`, `d.state` (as you do with rate and id in the tooltip tip - column names set property names with d3.tsv/csv, log `d` in the defer method to see).

Comment: I tried that approach too -- it caused the tooltip to show the county and state as undefined. I have a nagging sense there is something else I need to do, but I don't know what.   https://plnkr.co/edit/noSUVJXgQhDE1Q0R3TDZ?p=preview

Comment: And now I find an answer, of sorts, from another post that hadn't turned up in my previous searches: Apparently what I'm trying to do here can't be done at all this way because "....you cannot set two values for the same key."  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509772/choropleth-map-returning-undefined?rq=1

Comment: My bad, I misread a bit when looking at this to start. Can be done, I'll ad an answer momentarily.

Comment: My bad, I misread a bit when looking at this to start, you can't store multiple values for one key, but you can store an object for each key, in your case the object representing each row in the tsv would be fine. The answer below should clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to understand how `d3.map()` works. 
A d3 map creates key entry pairs, `map.get("key")` returns the value associated with that key. To create an entry in a map we use `map.set("key",value)`. In your code block you use:

```
unemployment.set(d.id, +d.rate, d.county, d.state);
```

Where `unemployment` is your map and `d` is a row in the tsv. Using this we set the value associated with each key (`d.id`) to be `d.rate`, which is only one part of the data we want in the original example. The extra parameters, `d.county` and `d.state` here are ignored.

Instead, we could use:

```
unemployment.set(d.id, d);
```

This will set the key to be `d.id` still, as above, but now the value is the entire row of the tsv that we want:

```
unemployment.get("06071"); // { id: "06071", rate: "6.2", state: "CA", county: "San Bernardino County" }
```

In the original example the value in the map was a string, but now it is an object representing a row in the tsv, so we need to address a few lines in the original example:

```
.attr("fill", function(d) { return color(unemployment.get(d.id)); })
```

Becomes:

```
.attr("fill", function(d) { return color(unemployment.get(d.id).rate); })
```

As we need to access the rate property of the mapped value.

And for the tooltip, we can use:

```
 .text(function(d) { var datum = unemployment.get(d.id); return "ID: " + datum.id + " - " + datum.county + ", " + datum.state + " - " + "Rate: " + datum.rate + "%"; });
```

Which gives us [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fsc215CSvFnXX3crMnFt?p=preview).

Comment: Awesome, that indeed does the trick. Thanks for the quick and detailed response -- it'll be some very helpful study material for me.

Comment: OK, so I tried this solution on a different data set (state crime rates instead of county unemployment) and keep tripping up. 

When I tried a state-crime version of Bostock's original (with non-verbose tooltips) it worked fine:  
 https://plnkr.co/edit/x1iHvYvIRbRCI0xSHx7T?p=preview 

But when I tried to apply the solution for the verbose tooltips to the state-crime map, I get only the color key and no map at all: 
 https://plnkr.co/edit/BchnbUv5nt2ylhfZY9Y1?p=preview 

Any ideas?